# How I can insert many columns of MYSQL with Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a file with data:

```
param1 = value1
param2 = value2
....
param100 = value100
```

Also, I have a MYSQL table looks this way:

```
      Param1 Param2 ... Param100
Row0  Value1 Value2 ... Value3
```

I have to parse my data file and to insert a row which consist of many columns.
I have succeed to parse a file and to create a list.
any suggestion how to insert it?
Currently I have:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="**",port=**,user="**",passwd="***",db="**") 
# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()
params = ""
values = ""
with open(filename) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        words = line.split(' ')
        if len(words) == 3:
      params+=words[0]
      params+=","
      values+=words[2].rstrip()
      values+=","
    # Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.

params = params[:-1]
values = values[:-1]

sql = """INSERT INTO BE_DB_status("""+params+""") VALUES ("""+values+""")s)"""
print sql
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
enter code here
```

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Parsing the file? Turning the file content into Python variables to hold the data? Building the SQL? Connecting to the database? Executing the SQL? Please post the code you've got so far and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you looking for a query, Python code, or both?

Comment: I have added a code